# How can I lock out non-authenticated users from a whole taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy hooking together different content types, everything is working as expected. However, I never want non-Admins to see the taxonomy pages, just names or other related fields in views on other pages. **How can hide all of this taxonomies pages from non-authenticated users?**

Specific example:

- Sales Contact (Node Type) - Sales contact name, address, phone, etc.
- Products (Node Type) - All sorts of assorted Product Details
- Sales Classifications (Taxonomy) - Types of contracts we have with Sales Contacts, and what products they cover.

Product pages and Sales Contact pages are public, but a Sales Classification page makes no sense to show end users. That said, on Product detail pages I'd like to show some of the Sales Classification fields to end users.

**Taxonomy Access Control** looked promising, but you can ether lock down the whole term (including related nodes) OR set it to do node permissions separately.

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I found Rabbit Hole (https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) which is a nice simple solution to just make pages 404 (which is great from an SEO perspective)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole), it seams to do everything I was looking for.  More details from the module's project page:

> Rabbit Hole is a module that adds the ability to control what should happen when an entity is being viewed at its own page.
>
> Perhaps you have a content type that never should be displayed on its own page, like an image content type that's displayed in a carousel. Rabbit Hole can prevent this node from being accessible on its own page, through node/xxx.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the drupal taxonomy views and set as one of the filters the admin role.

Comment: Do you mean Taxonomy Views Integrator? I've never used it before, but will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Panels to override the taxonomy path, then make one variant for authenticated users and another variant for anonymous users. (control access using selection rules)

Panels adds some setup overhead but will give you complete control over the information shown on the page.

Comment: Panels seems a little over kill...

Comment: @user327046 Sure, it might be overkill for this particular use case-- if your requirements don't change.  But if the requirements change later and you have to make it work in a different way, Panels will most likely have the options you need.  If you use another module, you may have to switch modules, which will be a lot more work in the long run.